# How to config RAML to return file

Tags: java, raml

I am using RAML with Java. Base on the RAML document, I can do the following to return a file for GET call

```
/file-content:
  description: The file to be reproduced by the client
  get:
    description: Get the file content
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          binary/octet-stream:
            example:
              !include heybulldog.mp3
```

Does anyone know how to return the whole file instead of transforming the file into binary stream?

Comment: What do you mean "return the whole file"? Do you only get a few bytes when you `GET file-content`? Also what do you mean by "transforming the file into binary stream"? Your transforming *from what*? Can you show the source code?